# How to switch the owner of a TF workspace?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm doing some work on a computer that has been used by a colleague. All relevant source code has already been mapped locally, so I would like continue using that workspace without remapping (it takes several hours to do the initial mapping, so that's why I would like to use what is already there).

The local mapping is write-protected when using my account, so I assume a solution is to transfer the ownership? I'm all ears for other workarounds as well.

I've tried the following in VS cmd prompt: `tf workspace <workspace-name>;<previous-owner> /newowner:<me>` and `tf workspace <workspace-name>;<previous-owner>`. Both activates an 'Edit workspace' GUI, but I'm not allowed to change anything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the input.

The workaround that ended up working was a bit convoluted (the steps in the [blog](https://colinsalmcorner.com/workspaces-updating-the-owner/) that Vito linked to didn't work, but it provided some useful tips). I'm not sure if I in reality just did a total remapping with extra steps, but it did at least feel much quicker than last time I set up the work environment from scratch. Here are the steps:

1. My colleague deleted his his workspace. I had to restart VS for the change to be detected locally.
2. I mapped my workspace to my colleagues deleted workspace.
3. When VS got all the files there were hundreds of merge conflicts of the type "already exists locally". Ctrl+a to select all conflicts and click "Keep existing version"
4. Now there were hundreds of files in "Pending Changes". I did "Undo" on all these.
5. Now I was 'up-to-date'

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1):

We could run this command to change the owner of the work space:

```
tf workspace Workspacename;Currentowner /newowner:newowner /collection:collectionurl
```

We could also refer to this [blog](https://colinsalmcorner.com/workspaces-updating-the-owner/) to update the Workspaces owner.

Answer (score 0):

Check `tf workspaces /updateUserName:OldUserName`. You can find the documentation here: [How to change the computer name and update the owner name for a workspace](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/buckh/how-to-change-the-computer-name-and-update-the-owner-name-for-a-workspace/), [Workspaces Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/workspaces-command?view=azure-devops)